# How many free rune pages do you start with?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that you can buy more rune pages in the store for 6300IP each.  I have a friend who was awarded Rammus and Corki for free, probably due to some glitch that thought he was signed up for his account longer than he actually was.  I know that they were awarded to players early on in the life of the game.

That same friend also has 3 rune pages, whereas I only have 2 available.  Is there a button I'm missing that will give me an extra free rune page?  Was he also mysteriously awarded a third rune page by some glitch?

Two rune pages is hardly enough to set up any kind of reasonable array, but I don't play nearly enough to warrant saving up 6300IP just to have the privilege of spending tens of thousands of IP on new runes for a jungler.  How do other people have 3 rune pages for free whereas I'm stuck with only 2?

Comment: There *was* an additional rune page given out, just like UFO Corki and Beta (King, as in Bowser) Rammus. Honestly, I just shelled out the RP for the 7-pack of rune pages. Totally worthwhile purchase, IMO.

Comment: I can't justify $20 for 7 rune pages when each rune page will take multiple thousands of IP to fill.

Comment: wha? Oftentimes rune pages mean you just want to swap out one set of GLYPHS|SEALS|MARKS. Swapping Armor Pen. for Magic Pen. for instance,  while keeping your +armor and +MR. It's a luxury convenience to be sure, but I make good use of it, and I never have bought runes with RP.

Comment: Well, you can't buy runes for RP.  But your point stands otherwise.  Extra runepages is a great addition.  Especially once you get all the base runes covered and start to play slightly different champions (e.g. Teemo; I use Attack Speed reds and one Attack Speed Quint on him).  If I could buy more than 10 rune/mastery pages, I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Y]ou will be able to purchase up to seven additional runes pages for a grand total of nine.
>
> — [Additional Rune Pages Available for Purchase!](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/additional-rune-pages-available-purchase)

9 - 7 = **2** for new accounts

QED

It seems like Riot has used the promise of a free rune page to [motivate their players to go vote](http://www.solomid.net/forums/index.php?/topic/4005-want-a-free-rune-page/) or participate in this or that.  Presumably everyone who had an account prior to then would have a bonus one for free.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Rune Page Guide](http://www.squidoo.com/league-of-legends-rune-pages-guide) you will have 2 rune pages. Some older accounts will have 3 rune pages because League of Legends won a contest and rewarded all its users that had voted.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to 20 rune pages. It used to cap out at 10, but they increased the limit several patches ago.